# How to use CMake to generate vs project, which link to some .dll files

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use Cmake to generate VS project, based on some dll file by

```
if(WIN32)
    MESSAGE(WINDOWS)
    LINK_LIBRARIES(${***_Test_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/Win32/Release/***.dll)
else(WIN32)
    MESSAGE(POSIX)
    LINK_LIBRARIES(${***_Test_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/POSIX/lib***.so)
endif(WIN32)
```

But when I open the generated project, build and it throw out

```
\***.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B0
```

Is anyone has ideas?

If do not use CMake, how to add **external dll**(not reference to some project) file in VS project. Is there any strict steps I can follow?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure those are valid .dll files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On Windows, you need to link against *.lib* and not against a *.dll*, that's stupid, but Microsoft uses the same *.lib* extension for *static* and *dynamic* libraries. There should be `***.lib` somewhere in `${***_Test_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/Win32/Release/`.

  ```
  LINK_LIBRARIES(${***_Test_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/Win32/Release/***.lib)
  ```
- If it is not the case, you can follow this article to build a `.lib` from a `.dll`: [How To Create 32-bit Import Libraries Without .OBJs or Source](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B131313&x=1&y=15). Briefly (taken from [Adrian Henke’s Blog](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/)), within a VS command prompt:

  ```
  dumpbin /exports C:\yourpath\yourlib.dll
  ```

This will print quite a bit of text to the console. However we are only interested in the functions:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

1    0 00017770 jcopy_block_row
2    1 00017710 jcopy_sample_rows
3    2 000176C0 jdiv_round_up
4    3 000156D0 jinit_1pass_quantizer
5    4 00016D90 jinit_2pass_quantizer
6    5 00005750 jinit_c_coef_controller
...etc
```

Now copy all those function names (only the names!) and paste them into a new textfile. Name the nextfile yourlib.def and put the line “EXPORTS” at its top. My yourlib.def file looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
jcopy_block_row
jcopy_sample_rows
jdiv_round_up
jinit_1pass_quantizer
jinit_2pass_quantizer
jinit_c_coef_controller
...
```

Now from that definition file, we can finally create the .lib file. We use the “lib” tool for this, so run this command in your Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
lib /def:C:\mypath\mylib.def /OUT:C:\mypath\mylib.lib
```